# I can't wrap a FlatList, it makes the FlatList height is over the wrapper

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

**Hello Everyone!**

I want to display my notification data inside a `Modal` and using a `FlatList`, I am using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal) for the `Modal` component, inside a Modal I have 3 main component like `header`, `body`, and `footer`.

`header` is just a title with the bottom line of it

`body` is a `FlatList`

and `footer` is a just Button for clear the notification

These 3 main components I wrap again with `View` component and I set the `maxHeight` for this (`View`) component

The `body` is the main issue here because the `FlatList` height is over the `View` height that I set the `maxHeight`, it's hard to explain and sorry, but you can see the picture at the bottom

> And the important one is that I can't use `flex:1` inside a Modal it's because a module that I use (`react-native-modal`) if I use `flex: 1` it makes `FlatList` disappear

**Picture**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjws2.jpg)

**Code of ModalNotificationShowcase.jsx**

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  memo,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import {View, Dimensions, Pressable, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {Divider, Button, Icon, List} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import {IconHelper, Text, Modal} from '../Helper';
import {useRealmInstance, useRealmObjects} from '../../hooks';
import moment from 'moment';
import util from '../../utils';
import ThemeContext from '../../themes/ThemeContext';

const NotificationItem = memo(props => {
  const {currentTheme} = props;
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState(
    currentTheme === 'light' ? '#EDF1F7' : '#1A2138',
  );
  const notif = props.data;
  const realm = props.realm;

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPressIn={() =>
        setBgColor(currentTheme === 'light' ? '#E4E9F2' : '#151A30')
      }
      style={{
        padding: 12,
        marginBottom: 12,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
      onPress={props.onPress}
      onPressOut={() =>
        setBgColor(currentTheme === 'light' ? '#EDF1F7' : '#1A2138')
      }
    >
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <IconHelper
          color={notif.name === 'reminder' ? '#FF3D71' : '#0095FF'}
          name={
            notif.name === 'reminder'
              ? 'alert-triangle-outline'
              : 'info-outline'
          }
          style={{marginRight: 8}}
          onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
        />
        <Text size={14} style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 4}}>
          {notif.message}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text size={12} hint>
          {moment(notif.createdAt).fromNow()}
        </Text>
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
          <IconHelper
            size={20}
            color='#FF3D71'
            name='trash-2-outline'
            underlayColor='#E4E9F2'
            onPress={() => {
              realm.write(() => {
                realm.delete(notif);
              });
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  );
});

const NotificationShowcase = props => {
  const realm = useRealmInstance();
  const notifications = useRealmObjects('notifications');
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 48,
        maxHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height - 48,
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
    >
      // =====
      // Header
      // =====
      <Text size={14} bold align='center' style={{padding: 12}}>
        Notifikasi
      </Text>
      <Divider />

      // =====
      // Body
      // =====
      <View style={{padding: 12, flexGrow: 1, overflow: 'hidden'}}>
        {notifications.isEmpty() ? (
          <Text
            size={14}
            align='center'
            hint
            style={{
              padding: 8,
              marginBottom: 12,
              backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? '#EDF1F7' : '#1A2138',
              borderRadius: 4,
            }}
          >
            Belum ada notifikasi untuk saat ini
          </Text>
        ) : (

          // ======================
          // The main issue is here
          // ======================
          <FlatList
            data={notifications}
            initialNumToRender={0}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
            updateCellsBatchingPeriod={120}
            numColumns={1}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id.toString()}
            renderItem={items => {
              const notif = items.item;
              return (
                <NotificationItem
                  data={notif}
                  realm={realm}
                  currentTheme={theme}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        )}

        // =====
        // Footer
        // =====
        {!notifications.isEmpty() && (
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Button
              size='small'
              appearance='outline'
              accessoryLeft={props => (
                <Icon {...props} name='trash-2-outline' />
              )}
              onPress={() => {
                realm.write(() => {
                  realm.delete(notifications);
                });
              }}
            >
              Hapus semua
            </Button>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const ModalNotificationShowcase = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  let Modal_ref;

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    show: () => Modal_ref.show(),
    hide: () => Modal_ref.hide(),
  }));

  return (
    <Modal
      backdropStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(9, 44, 76, .32)'}}
      onBackdropPress={() => Modal_ref.hide()}
      ref={refs => (Modal_ref = refs)}
    >
      <NotificationShowcase
        navigate={props.navigate}
        onPressNotifItem={() => Modal_ref.hide()}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
});

export default ModalNotificationShowcase;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

```
const NotificationShowcase = props => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        margin: 24,
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
    >
      ...
      // =====
      // Body
      // =====
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        // ...
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but, still same, even worst I can't scroll a `FlatList`

Comment: remove overflow property from `NotificationShowcase`'s Body `<View style={{padding: 12, flexGrow: 1, overflow: 'hidden'}}>`

Comment: I do, it's still

Comment: I am not sure why you can't use `flex`. In my past experience, I used `flex` just inside `Modal`.

Comment: I think it's an issue in `react-native-modal`

Comment: I've updated my answer with proper style changes using flex. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224646/discussion-between-baymax-and-firmansyah).